# Referencing a binding library in a blank android project error

Tags: android, xamarin, dji-sdk

I have some JAR files from a SDK that I want to use. I created a Binding Library project and imported my JAR files in there. When I create a blank android project and add as reference that binding library I've created and build the solution I got error like: error: package dji.sdk.base.DJIBaseComponent does not exist dji.sdk.base.DJIBaseComponent.DJIComponentListener

How can I fix this?

PS: If more information is needed, let me know.

Thanks

EDIT: First screen shot is building just the Dji_SDK_Library project (this is the Binding Library):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yGUW.png)

The second screen shot is building all together. The FlightControlApp project is that Android project that references Dji_SDK_Library. 
As you can see, the errors are in FlightControlApp, and that dji folder that I marked is generated because of that reference. Before I reference the library in the project that dji folder was not in there. I think that is a problem how it is generated, missing some files maybe. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djL2p.png)

Comment: Can you paste a few screenshots and error logs of what you're experiencing? Is your Android Binding building successfully before you are adding it as a reference? Does the Android Binding project generate those two types?

Comment: Yes the binding library built successfully. The errors are in that android project, but refers to the binding library. Something is not imported I guess, but can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, by adding .jar files to the Android project too.

Comment: Emilian, Can you please share your bindings for iOS and Android and post it here: forum.dev.dji.com/thread-31963-1-1.html Thanks/ 
mulțumesc.  Can we connect regarding this binding and how you are going to approach this using Xamarin. I am a c#.net developer with a little xamarin experience and I would like to play with DJI platform. I am currently enrolled in this course: coursera.org/specializations/robotics and I would like to have a drone platform to try to experiment. My email is r a d o s l a v @ e v e r e s t k c . n e t